# Missing rows when selecting from 2 tables

Tags: sql

Hi and sorry if that's a stupud question but I am trying to get results from two different tables and since one of them might have zero records I am not sure how to proceed. Here is the  query:

```
SELECT aid.*, T.ItemId, T.Total, T.Stack
FROM (SELECT ItemId, Stack, count(ItemId) as Total FROM auction_house WHERE Sale = 0 GROUP BY ItemId,     Stack) as T, ahbot_item_data aid
WHERE T.ItemId = aid.ItemId
AND T.Stack = aid.Stack
```

Basically I want to get a list of items from the aid table, and the current count of those items in the ah table. But since the count might just be zero, it might not return that row. I want the row and the Total to be 0.

Thank you in advance ^^;;

Comment: Look at right or left joins.  These type of joins will give you results from one table, regardless of whether it is in the other table.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what @Twelfth was saying, you want to have a left outer join, which always outputs data from the left table even if there is no matching data in the right table.

```
SELECT
    aid.ItemId,
    count(ah.ItemId) AS "Total",
    aid.Stack
FROM 
    ahbot_item_data aid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN auction_house ah
    ON (aid.ItemID = ah.ItemID AND aid.Stack = ah.Stack)
GROUP BY
    aid.ItemID, aid.Stack
```

Comment: Would it be possible then to check if "Total" is > than aid.LiveStock ?

Comment: Yep you can either build this into a sub-query, similar to what you did in your original code for T. Or you can using the HAVING clause similar to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f21c/4/0

Comment: Indeed, using your example and adding a few missing pieces (my own fault) and using HAVING fix it :D Thank you all for helping out !

Answer (score 0):

You are using old syntax...I'm going to switch to join syntax (newer and more accepted...same effect, easier to read).  What you want is an 'outer join', which will produce nulls where no record is found.  I'll arrange the tables and we'll use a left outer join

```
SELECT aid.*, T.ItemId, T.Total, T.Stack
FROM ahbot_item_data aid left join (SELECT ItemId, Stack, count(ItemId) as Total FROM auction_house WHERE Sale = 0 GROUP BY ItemId,     Stack) as T, 
on T.ItemId = aid.ItemId
AND T.Stack = aid.Stack
```

I'm not entirely sure on the syntax anymore...but it's also possible to use != to do this outer join in the syntax you've used (where aid.itemID != t.itemID   I think?)